# how to create a dict from row in sublist?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

> With  this DataFrame:

```
Gp  Wo Me CHi
1   0   1   0
2   1   0   0
3   0   1   0
4   1   0   0
5   0   2   0
6   1   0   0
```

I would like create a dictionary like :

```
a={'Gp':['Wo', 'Me','CHi']}
```

but in the case column 'Gp'  row 5  the value of column 'Me' is 2 ,how I can convert like this value  :

```
a={5:[0, [1,1],0]}
```

Like create another list if the value is > 1:

Comment: I'll change, thanks.

Comment: can you explain the logic please thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.itterrows()` and check if the row value of the column 'Me' is equal to 2 and write an if statement:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Me'] == 2:
        print({row['Gp']: [row['Wo'], [1, 1], row['CHi']]})
    else:
        print({row['Gp']: [row['Wo'], row['Me'], row['CHi']]})
```

This will output the following dictionaries:

> {1: [0, 1, 0]}
>
> {2: [1, 0, 0]}
>
> {3: [0, 1, 0]}
>
> {4: [1, 0, 0]}
>
> {5: [0, [1, 1], 0]}
>
> {6: [1, 0, 0]}

**EDIT** Based on the comment:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Me'] <= 1:
        print({row['Gp']: [row['Wo'], row['Me'], row['CHi']]})
    else:
        print({row['Gp']: [row['Wo'], [1 for _ in range(row['Me'])], row['CHi']]})
```

Comment: Is not possible like  *[1] if >1 ? for example in the case that are 6 you need create for each ==2,==3,==4,==5,==6 .

Comment: I added this option to my answer